# How do I get started with JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I've never used any third party library before. What should I do after I downloaded  `jfreechart-1.0.14.tar.gz`?

I don't know if I'm doing these things right:
1. Put the `jcommon-1.0.17.jar` and `jfreechart-1.0.14.jar` at the same directory as my source code.
2. Import needed class in the source code (e.g. `import org.jfree.util.Rotation;`)

Many articles tell you how to do this in IDEs. But instead of IDEs, I'm writing codes with vim and compile by myself. So, assume I didn't do any thing wrong, how should I compile the source code with `javac` and run the code with `java`?

---

Edit:

Here's my file layout:
./src
 | - test.java
./lib
 | - jcommon-1.0.17.jar
 | - jfreechart-1.0.14.jar

I compile by
`javac -cp "lib/*" -d classes/ src/test.java`
then run by
`java -cp classes:lib/jcommon-1.0.17.jar:jfreechart-1.0.14.jar test`

However, some error occurs:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/data/general/PieDataset

How can I resolve this problem?

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/data/general/PieDataset  
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)  
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)  
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)  
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)  
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)  
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jfree.data.general.PieDataset  
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)  
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)  
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)  
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  
... 6 more
```

Comment: This article may help:http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Compile_Java_with_Sun_JDK_javac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries shouldn't be at the same place as the source code. If you don't want to use a build tool like Gradle yet, which would handle your library dependencies, then I suggest using the following layout:

```
project
    src
        .java files here, organized in a folder tree matching the package tree
    classes
        compiled .class files here
    lib
        .jar files here
```

To compile, go in the project directory and execute the following command:

```
javac -cp lib/jfreechart-1.0.14.jar:lib/jcommon-1.0.17.jar -d classes src/com/foo/bar/MyClass.java src/com/foo/bar/MyOtherClass.java
```

To run your app, execute the following command:

```
java -cp classes:lib/jfreechart-1.0.14.jar:lib/jcommon-1.0.17.jar com.foo.bar.MyClass
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `lib/*` instead `lib/jfreechart-1.0.14.jar:lib/jcommon-1.0.17.jar` (sorry for that silly question, don't have JDK now to test it)?

Comment: Yes, it is possible since Java 6 : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: Shouldn't it be ``;`` instead of ``:``?

Comment: `;` on Windows, `:` on Unix (Linux, Mac, etc.).

Comment: I don't get what is ``com.foo.bar.MyClass``. Also, why both answer has the directory ``com``? Is that some kind of convention in Java?

Comment: com.foo.bar.MyClass is the fully qualified name of your class. Classes in Java are organized in packages. If the class MyClass is in the package com.foo.bar, its fully qualified name is com.foo.bar.MyClass. That's the name you use in import statement for example (`import java.util.List;`). The convention for packages is to use your domain name written backwards, followed by whatever structure you want. So if your domain name is `foo.com` and your project is `bar`, the main package would be `com.foo.bar`. That's why jfreechart classes are under `org.jfree.chart`.

Comment: First, put your test class in a package, and respect tha Java naming conventions: classes start with an uppercase letter. Second, add jfreechart to the classpath. You put jcommon twice in the classpath.

Comment: That was a typo. I did put jfreechart in the classpath.

Comment: Are you on Windows, on Linux, or on Mac? Why don't you use `-cp "lib/*"` like you're doing to compile?

Comment: I'm using Linux. The reason is that I don't know how to use ``classes`` and ``lib/*`` together.

Comment: I don't see what is wrong. Please post the full stack trace of the exception in your question. You execute Java from the directory just above the lib and classes directory, right?

Comment: Now I see it. You forgot `lib/` before `jfreechart-1.0.14.jar` in the -cp option.

Comment: How want to get started with JFreeChart. I have noticed that when I down looaded the JFreeChart library and unzipped the file there were tones of Java files. But how do you know how to put them together. There was a couple of demo.java in the folder but that only woudl show there demo which I could manipulate around. But I want to make my own graphs and would like to do them with out a lot of hassle. I have never really completely understood building the Jar file into a project because I just never have to do that in most projects that I work on.